# A special subset of uniformly distributed numbers is still uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability

Assume that I have a value range [1,1000].

I uniformly choose 10 numbers from [1,1000].

Assume that the chosen numbers are a1, a2, ..., a10.

Besides, assume that they are ordered so that a1< a2< ...< a10.

Here comes my question.

If I always choose 10 numbers, order these 10 numbers, and always pick the first three numbers (e.g., a1, a2, and a3) from the ordered result, then can I still claim that these three numbers are uniformly chosen from [1,1000]?

On the other hand, if I always choose 10 numbers, order these 10 numbers, and always pick those at even-positions (e.g., a2, a4, a6, a8, and a10) from the ordered result, then can I still claim that these five numbers are uniformly chosen from [1,1000]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

If you have $k$ uniformly distributed random variables in $[1,N]$ then the expected value of $a_1 + a_k$  will always be $N$.

To see this, for every $i$ set
$$b_i = N+1 - a_{k+1-i}.$$
So $b_1 = N+1 - a_k$, $b_2 = N +1 - a_{k-1}$ up to $b-k = N+1-a_1$.

Now if I choose a uniformly distributed random variable $a\in[1,N]$ then $b=N+1-a$ is also uniformly distributed in $[1,N]$ so my $b_i$ are distributed exactly the same as by $a_i$.

So $E(b_i) = E(a_i)$ for every $i$ and in particular $E(a_1 + a_k) = E(b_1 + a_k) = N+1$.

In both your guesses you remove the lowest number, but not the highest so the expected value of the lowest remaining number plus the highest remaining number must be strictly greater than $1000$ and the remaining numbers cannot be independent uniforms.

The only way of removing some of your $a_i$ such that the remaining values are iid uniform is to remove each of them independently with a fixed probability $p$.

Comment: sorry, what's your b_i's definition here?

Comment: you mean if I sample k values, the expected value of sum of the largest and smallest samples is N? Can you give me some reference? I google some order statistic results but cannot find it.

Comment: Slight mistake I meant $N+1$, but the argument's the same.  I've expanded it, but you won't find a reference, it's not a big theorem.